# Adding a manual subscription to mapped objects and passing active object when UI changes

Tags: knockout.js

I get my JSON data from a web service and use the mapping plugin to create observable objects.
I'd like to add a manual subscription to each objects `Pay` property that can pass the data object to a function.

ie: I have  `data-bind="foreach: { data: customerEnquiryCollection }"`

and in the loop of the foreach  `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked :Pay" />`

and in my View Model, when I pull data from the service:

```
var results = ko.observableArray();
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);
for (var i = 0; i < results().length; i++) {
    var obj = results()[i];

    obj.Pay.subscribe(function (checked) {
        checkPayGroups(checked, obj.EnquiryId());
    }.bind(this));

    customerEnquiryCollection.push(obj);                            
};
```

The value for `checked` is always passed correctly, but I'm getting seemingly random results for obj.EnquiryId(). I expect this has something to do with `this` and what object is actually being passed? but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` will change every iteration of the for loop. So when `Pay` changes, it'll get the `EnquiryId` of the last result.
Try creating a new scope when iterating over `results`:

```
var results = ko.observableArray();
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, results);
ko.utils.arrayForEach(results(), function(obj) {

    obj.Pay.subscribe(function (checked) {
        checkPayGroups(checked, obj.EnquiryId());
    }.bind(this));

    customerEnquiryCollection.push(obj);                            
});
```

Comment: Your answer has taught me a lot. Thank you.